# Venn Diagram Problem - Set of Athletes

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a group of athletes, 38 enjoy rugby, 12 enjoy soccer and 24 enjoy tennis. Of these, 8 athletes like all three activities, while 30 like only one of them.

How many athletes like only two of the three activities?

Could someone explain how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_n$ denote the number of athletes liking exactly $n$ activities. We have the following relations:
$$E_1+2E_2+3E_3=38+12+24=74,E_1=30,E_3=8$$
(The first relation can be justified by hatching a Venn diagram three different ways.) From this we get the answer as
$$E_2=\frac{74-3×8-30}2=10$$

Answer (score 1):

More elementary solution:

$38+12+24 = 74$. But we overcount the number of people that like all by a factor of 3 (one for each sport) and the number of people that like 2 by a factor of 2 (two of the three sports.)

So we have $74-24 = 50$, where $24$ is the overlap. Then, since $30$ people only like one, the number of people that like two are $50-30=20$. Almost. We overcounted by a factor of 2, so we divide to get $$\frac{20}{2} = \boxed{10.}$$